# What happened to Auth loginError in CakePHP v2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

There used to be a [`AuthComponent->loginError` method](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html#loginerror) in CakePHP v1.3. But that now seems to have disappeared in [CakePHP v2.0 authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

There's no reference to it in the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html). Just:

> "The AuthComponent was entirely re-factored for 2.0."

Anyone know what happened to it?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

You can simply send the message if login() returns false:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Important: Use login() without arguments! See warning below.
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            // Prior to 2.3 use
            // `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        }
        // HERE:
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default',
            array(),
            'auth'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Yeah I saw that - and I'd impemented that too. But then I figured it wasn't required since I had `loginError` already ... and then I realised that `loginError` doesn't do anything any more. So I was curious as to what happened to it

Answer (score 1):

Carlos's Answer is correct, but you could simplify the flash by just using

```
$this->Flash->error('Username or password is incorrect');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/flash.html